# Duda sobre validación de datos de un login sobre un echo y encriptado de password Php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, login, encriptación, echo

Estoy validando datos con una bd para iniciar sesión como usuario. Quiero que se muestre un echo cuando los datos no coinciden y luego un header para recargar la página, pero el echo no salta. Está dentro de un if, si lo pongo fuera si funciona, pero no entiendo por qué.

Mi otra duda es al encriptar una pass, creo que lo he puesto bien pero al introducir los datos me los da por incorrectos, en la bd esta bien, y si quito la encriptación de la pass si funciona el código, me podéis decir porque está mal?

aquí el archivo que valida los datos del login:

```
<?php
include 'conn_bd.php';
session_start();

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'] ?? null;
$password = $_POST['password'] ?? null;

if ($usuario && $password) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_login WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$password'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado-> fetch_assoc();

    $password_bd = $row['password'];
    $password_c = sha1($password);

    if($row['usuario'] == $usuario && $password_bd == $password_c){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("location: index_user.php");
    }else{
        echo 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos';
        header("location: login.php");
    }
}
```

Y aquí la parte del form del html:

```
    <?php
    include("conn_bd.php");
    include("validacion.php");
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ?> <br><br>
    
            <form action="validacion.php" method="post" id="formulario">
                <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" maxlength="40" size="53" > <br><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" maxlength="100" size="53" ><br><br>
                <input type="password" name="checkpass" id="checkpass" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña" maxlength="100" size="53" > <br><br>

                <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Iniciar Sesión"> <br><br><br>
                <p id="avisos"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="redes-container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="vimeo"><i class="fa-brands fa-vimeo-v"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="pinterest"><i class="fa-brands fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div id="copyright">
            <p>&copy; 215 Files 2023</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="../js/js_form_login.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Un saludo!!

Comment: Es como si dijeras: "Quiero que cargues login.php, pero en lugar de cargarla muestra éste mensaje". Considera enviar el mensaje por parámetro GET.

Comment: Le estoy diciendo 'si la info de los inputs coincide con la de la bd, ves a index, si no, muestra este mensaje y ves a login (la misma página) pero el mensaje no lo muestra aunque si redirige, es decir, hace una cosa y la otra no, y no entiendo porqué. No entiendo tampoco por qué enviarlo por GET

Comment: Los encabezados -como su nombre sugiere- van por delante. La [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) dice claramente: *"Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla"*.

Comment: Vale, no había caído en eso, pero sigue sin mostrarme el echo, y no entiendo por que, ¿no hay otra manera de mostrar un mensaje para que se vea después de que el header cargue la página?